# Carousel indicators rendering as base tag

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, carousel

My `carousel-indicators` are not rendering as they should even if the carousel itself is, I've tried many fixes but none of them worked, here's what they look like : [image]

As you can see they are not on the good position and the style class doesn't seems to apply for it, anyone knows a fix or what I did wrong here ?

Thank's in advance for your help

**body.component.html**

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" role="listbox">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="4"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <a class="carousel-item active" href="#one!" ><img src="../../assets/Couv-leaflet-Food-Processing.jpg"></a>
    <a class="carousel-item" href="#two!"><img src="../../assets/Couv-leaflet-In-Plant-Automotive.jpg"></a>
    <a class="carousel-item" href="#three!"><img src="../../assets/Couv-leaflet-DrinkingWater&Beverage.jpg"></a>
    <a class="carousel-item" href="#four!"><img src="../../assets/Couv-leaflet-Textile-Machinery.jpg"></a>
    <a class="carousel-item" href="#five!"><img src="../../assets/Couv-leaflet-Industrial-Machinery.jpg"></a>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <titledigital leaflets</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=yes">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.carousel').carousel();
  });
  $('.carousel').carousel({
    interval: 2000
  })

</script>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It works fine, please insert bootstrap CDN and your problem solved

Comment: @NishargShah When I add the bootstrap CDN the whole carousel disappear

Comment: can you create a snippet of it?

Comment: I think I got it to work, it seems that it was a jQuery version conflict

Comment: @NishargShah the problem persist so I made a stackblitz, from what I see it comes from the `carousel-item` class, when I change it to `item` it "works", here's the link if you want to have a look https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-9nygdu?file=src/app/body/body.component.html

Comment: do you want carousel from material or bootstrap?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226103/discussion-between-zephyr-and-nisharg-shah).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please insert Bootstrap CDN into your `angular.json` and it will work as expected

```
"styles": [
  "styles.css"
],
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using boostrap classes, you should add this link to your `<head></head>`

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Comment: When I add it the carousel doesn't render anymore which is what I don't understand